# How to create a homescreen shortcut via ADB?

Tags: adb, home-screen-shortcuts

I'm using as an example the open-source app ConnectBot to demonstrate what I want to achieve. I can create a connection's shortcut through the homescreen's widget functionality, but I want to know how to create shortcuts through `adb` if possible.

Part of the app's `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".HostListActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:resizeableActivity="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

            <data android:scheme="ssh"/>
            <data android:scheme="telnet"/>
            <data android:scheme="local"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

From the source code of `HostListActivity.java`:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // launch off to console details
        Uri uri = host.getUri();

        Intent contents = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        contents.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        if (makingShortcut) {
            // create shortcut if requested
            ShortcutIconResource icon = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(
                    HostListActivity.this, R.mipmap.icon);

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, contents);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, host.getNickname());
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, icon);

            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();

        } else {
            // otherwise just launch activity to show this host
            contents.setClass(HostListActivity.this, ConsoleActivity.class);
            HostListActivity.this.startActivity(contents);
        }
    }
```

So in order to make a shortcut icon of a particular connection I tried the following:

```
adb shell am broadcast -n org.connectbot/org.connectbot.HostListActivity
-a android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT --es android.intent.extra.shortcut.INTENT '"intent://user@host:XXXX/#HostNickname#Intent;scheme=ssh;package=org.connectbot;end"'
--es android.intent.extra.shortcut.NAME "ShortcutName" --esn android.intent.extra.shortcut.ICON_RESOURCE
```

The result I get:

```
Broadcasting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT flg=0x400000 cmp=org.connectbot/.HostListActivity (has extras) }
Broadcast completed: result=0
```

But nothing happens. If I replace `broadcast` with `start`, HostListActivity fires up and shows all stored connections. When I click on the host for which I want to make a shortcut, the activity closes (same as when I'm manually adding a shortcut via the widget screen), however no shortcut is added anywhere to the homescreen.

By the way the `intent://` URI that is passed as an extra is correct. I can succesfully use that URI to open a particular connection with ConnectBot:

```
adb shell am start '"intent://user@host:XXXX/#HostNickname#Intent;scheme=ssh;package=org.connectbot;end"'
```

Comment: To clarify the question is: "*How to fire an Intent with action `android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT` (and other required extras) from ADB shell to the `HostListActivity` of ConnectBot app so that in turn it creates a home screen shortcut as specified in the sent Intent.*". In my opinion it's a development oriented question because what happens inside `HostListActivity` (the interaction with Android's ShortcutManager) cannot be observed or controlled by the end user. It's up to the developer of the app how they handle the received Intent. Without knowing that the question cannot be answered.

Comment: But we do know what happens in HostListActivity. It shows a list of stored connections. When the activity is called with Intent action `android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT` (this is how the activity is called when I manually try to add a ConnectBot shortcut via the home's widget screen) and the user clicks on a host, instead of connecting to said host, it creates an Intent with extras `EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT`, `EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME` and `EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE`.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question because I'm not asking for help to understand or modify the above code... The question is how to translate this in `adb` commandline terms and use it with activity manager.

Comment: Please see the [shortcut Activity guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/creating-shortcuts#pinned) and the [four ways](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#as) (working and legacy) a shortcut can be pinned to the home screen. An Intent with [`ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT) is fired by the launcher app to the target app (which is selected by the user from the ...

Comment: ... [list of widget provider apps](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/LauncherApps#getShortcutConfigActivityList(java.lang.String,%20android.os.UserHandle))). The user selects an item from the list of shortcuts. The target app [creates an Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ShortcutManager#createShortcutResultIntent(android.content.pm.ShortcutInfo)) according to the user's selection and delivers it back to the launcher app which the latter uses to create the shortcut. I hope it clears your confusion.

Comment: And that's what I'm trying to do via `adb`. We know that the target app is launched with `ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT`, we know that the target app returns an intent with the above mentioned extras, we know what these extras contain (perhaps I shouldn't set a null value for `EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE` though) and we also have a working `intent://` URI that will be used when the user clicks on the shortcut. How do we make all this an `adb am` command?

Comment: "*... we know that the target app returns an intent with the above mentioned extras ...*". The target app returns this Intent by calling the [`setResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setResult(int)) API. How would you do that using `am`? The launcher app receives the returned Intent because it's waiting for the result. How would you make the launcher app wait for your `am` command? It's simply not possible without using proper APIs from the Java code.

Comment: Okay I see what you're saying. I was assuming that we could somehow bypass the launcher app perhaps. So in theory, we could instead start a particular shortcut-creating activity of the launcher app via adb and try similar extras by trial and error to trigger the shortcut creation?

Comment: You can request the developer of the launcher app to add an Activity that takes the shortcut specs from an explicit Intent fired from anywhere.